# Explicitly specify "FROM" table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I currently have the following query:

```
query = self.session.query(Student, School).join(
    Person.student, aliased=True).join(
    Student.school, aliased=True).filter(
    Person.id == 1)
```

Which compiles to this SQL.

```
SELECT student.id AS student_id, student.school_id AS student_school_id, student.person_id AS student_person_id, school.id AS school_id, school.name AS school_name 
FROM student, school, person JOIN student AS student_1 ON person.id = student_1.person_id JOIN school AS school_1 ON school_1.id = student_1.school_id 
WHERE person.id = :id_1
```

I want the query to remain exactly as it is but I want the from statement to be exclusively from the `Person` model.  So something like

```
SELECT * FROM person JOIN ... WHERE person.id = :id_1
```

I think the `aliased` kwarg is messing up the from condition.  Removing the `aliased` kwarg fixes the behavior but I need the aliased kwarg for special use cases.  How can I remove the `student` and `school` tables from the "FROM" statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aliased` argument to `.join` uses anonymous aliasing, meaning the `Student` and `School` you pass to `session.query` are different 'instances' of the table.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased

aliased_student = aliased(Student)
aliased_school = aliased(School)

query = (
    session.query(aliased_student, aliased_school)
    .select_from(Person)
    .join(aliased_student, Person.student)
    .join(aliased_school, Student.school)
    .filter(Person.id == 1))
```

Here you can see that you can tell `.join` which alias to use when joining to a relationship.